# How are nested branches handled on the Pascal architecture?

Tags: cuda

While reading through the CUDA programming guide:

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#simt-architecture

I came across the following paragraph:

> Prior to Volta, warps used a single program counter shared amongst all 32 threads in the warp together with an active mask specifying the active threads of the warp. As a result, threads from the same warp in divergent regions or different states of execution cannot signal each other or exchange data, and algorithms requiring fine-grained sharing of data guarded by locks or mutexes can easily lead to deadlock, depending on which warp the contending threads come from.

However, at the start of the same section, it says:

> Individual threads composing a warp start together at the same program address, but they have their own instruction address counter and register state and are therefore free to branch and execute independently.

Which appears to be contradict the other paragraph, because it mentions that threads have their own program counter, while the first paragraph claims they do not.

How is this active mask handled when a program has nested branches (such as if statements)?

How does a thread know when the divergent part which it did not need to execute is done, if it supposedly does not have its own program counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is highly speculative, but based on the available information and some educated guessing, I believe the way it used to work before Volta is that each warp would basically have a stack of "return addresses" as well as the active mask or probably actually the inverse of the active mask, i.e., the mask for running the other part of the branch once you return. With this design, each warp can only have a single active branch at any point in time. A consequence of this is that the warp scheduler could only ever schedule the one active branch of a warp. This makes fair, starvation-free scheduling impossible and gives rise to all the limitations there used to be, e.g., concerning locks.

I believe what they basically did with Volta is that there is now a separate such stack and program counter for each branch (or maybe even for each thread; it should be functionally indistinguishable whether each thread has its own physical program counter or whether there is one shared program counter per branch; if you really want to find out about this implementation detail you maybe could design some experiment based on checking at which point you run out of stack space). This change gives all current branches an explicit representation and allows the warp scheduler to at any time pick threads from any branch to run. As a result, the warp scheduling can be made starvation-free, which gets rid of many of the restrictions that earlier architectures had…